# Qemu Makefile error make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile.rb'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, makefile, qemu

I have a make file that returns the error: make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile.rb', whenever I attempt to run. Here is my Makefile:

```
SDKDIR=./sdk

help:

    @echo "Makefile for Building Dev Operating System."

    @echo "Usage: make [ all | clean | help | build | run] " 

    @echo ""

    @echo

all: 

    @echo "Building Kernel"

    make -C ./kernel

    @echo "Building SDK"

    make -C ./sdk

    @echo "Building Userland"

    make -C ./userland


build:

    zip -r devos-$(VERSION).zip ./

run:

    @echo "Running Dev Operating System."

    cd ./sdk && sudo bash ./diskimage.sh

    cd ./sdk && ./qemu.sh

clean:

    make -C ./kernel clean

    make -C ./userland clean
```

I am using qemu for macOS Serria on Homebrew.

Comment: You can't just be running `make` alone, or else this is not the makefile you're using.  Please show the exact command you invoked and the exact output you got (cut and paste).

Comment: cd /*myusername*

Comment: make Makefile.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that the name of your makefile is `Makefile.rb`?

That's not how you run make on a makefile.  Any non-option arguments passed to `make` are considered targets that make should try to build; that's why when you say `make Makefile.rb` make tells you there's nothing to do to build that target: the file already exists and it has no prerequisites so it can't be out of date.

Normally when make starts it reads makefiles in the current directory named `Makefile` or `makefile` or `GNUmakefile`.  If you want it to parse a different makefile, you use the `-f` option:

```
make -f Makefile.rb
```

You can read the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) or the man page with `man make` to learn more about how to run make.